# Directly Pass json object instead of file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this tutorial](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/using-tiled-and-canvas-to-render-game-screens) to help me with rendering a tiled map. I want to try this example but CORS seems to be stopping me on the local side. It is not my main issue though, because i need to use dynamic JSON data, instead of directly including the json file. The relevant code is like this :

```
....
        renderLayers: function(layers) {
          layers = $.isArray(layers) ? layers : this.data.layers;
          layers.forEach(this.renderLayer);
        },
        loadTileset: function(json) {
          this.data = json;
          this.tileset = $("<img />", { src: json.tilesets[0].image })[0]
          this.tileset.onload = $.proxy(this.renderLayers, this);
        },
        load: function(name) {
          return $.ajax({
            url: "mountain.json",
            type: "JSON"
          }).done($.proxy(this.loadTileset, this));
        }
      };

      scene.load("mountain");
```

Ideally, i would want to have a var that holds the whole json object and change the above method to support that. I tried a few things, but i lack jquery knowledge, so i think i kinda messed this.

Please notice that the sample gist is here :

https://gist.github.com/shaneriley/4078905

Could anyone help me with how i would go about directly using the json object instead of including the json file ? Thanks !

Comment: So, you want to remove the Ajax call and instead add the object definition to the JavaScript source code? Just create a variable `var data = {... all the data here ...};` and call the function `scene.loadTileset(data);`.

Comment: You should probable update the wording of the title. JSON is a language-independent, textual data-exchange format (like XML). When you say "raw JSON", it sounds like you want to get a string containing JSON, and *not* parse it. But reading the rest of the question, it sounds like that's not what you want.

Comment: Thank you Felix King. I updated the title, good catch. I'll try your suggestion in a few and let you know if that works, thanks !

Comment: Almost there it looks like. The CORS warning is suppressed, but i get a "has no method 'proxy'" error when trying that. It kinda looks like your method is doing what i want though and there's some other proxy that's stopping it because of the $.proxy in this case.

Comment: Sounds like `$` doesn't refer to jQuery, or you are using an really old version of jQuery. Try `jQuery.proxy` instead.

Comment: hmm, i actually included the very latest jquery, and it fixed this. Now i am getting "Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.", lol :D  This must be related to CORS, i feel that your suggestion has worked, though i still can't verify.